# why the <icon /> is not displayed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, icons

[This is my header item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2s14.png)

[This is my header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMd6L.png)

When I want do display icon in header through the header item, Im using props to diplay icon but the icon cannot displayed, help me please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please make sure to post code as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: thanks for reminding me, I've overcome it

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `<Icon />` inside your `HeaderItem` with `{Icon}` then it will works:

```js
const HeaderItem = ({ Icon, title }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {Icon}

      <p>{title}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

In your header file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { HomeIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";

function Header() {
  // ...

  return (
    <HeaderItem Icon={<HomeIcon />} title="Title" />
  )
}
```

Comment: It's not error but not displayed

Comment: Maybe you are importing the `HomeIcon` in a wrong way, pls check my edited answer.

Comment: I think yes and I just realized it, thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use `prop` as a `component` you should write it in `{}` for ex `{Icon}`. If you are importing a independent component then only you can specify in `<> </>`